# Corupted keyboard layout

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, input-languages

When I try to add `Persian` keyboard layout on my Windows 7 x64, the keyboard doesn't show up in the language bar. For example, when I add `English`, `Arabic`, and `Persian` keyboard layouts as shown in the following figure,

[image]

the only available languages will be `English` and `Arabic`:

[image]

The properties for the `Persian` layout shows a blank keyboard:

[image]

I had installed a Persian accounting software with probably caused the problem. I've tried `sfc /scannow` to revert changes to system files, if any, but `sfc` didn't find any issues.

Comment: Maybe you should install the locales separately?

Comment: @EugeneS: No. The `Persian` locale along many other languages is a part of Windows 7. I have no problem with installing `Persian` locale on other PCs running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had such an experience with installing custom keyboard layout using setup programs like "XP Farsi Keyboard".

This setup make similar dll to Kbdfa.dll in System32 folder: kbdfapsoft.dll

I resolve the problem using:

1- Search Windows folder for kbdfa.dll.
     I found these:

```
32 bit dlls:(6.50 KB)
 C:\Windows\System32\kbdfa.dll
 C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-i..l-keyboard-00000429_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_46c321d27ba117ab\kbdfa.dll

64 bit dlls:(6.00 KB)
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kbdfa.dll
 C:\Windows\winsxs\wow64_microsoft-windows-i..l-keyboard-00000429_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_5117cc24b001d9a6\kbdfa.dll
```

2- Copy and paste kbdfa32.dll from winsxs folder to appropriate system32 or SysWOW64 Folders.

3- If you have files like kbdfa*.dll (ie: kbdfapsoft.dll) , Copy and replace appropriate kbdfa.dll to its location, ususally system32 folder with the same name(ie: kbdfapsoft.dll).

4- Copy and paste 32 bit dlls (kbdfa.dll and if you have kbdfa*.dll) into system32\dllcache

5- Remove Perian Keyboard and add it againg.
And its done.

It is better Idea to use standard windows layout.You can use ctrl+shift+2 to type zwnj (Zero Width None Joiner).

Some useful links:

[The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)

[traylayout-1.2.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/farsitools/files/Mehrsoft%20TrayLayout/1.2/) 
for windows xp to mimic enhanced kbdfa.dll without actual replace of system files.